# power designer CHECK constraint behind tables and function

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints, powerdesigner

Could I change order in generated script for *CHECK* constraint on *TABLE*? 
I need to generate *Check Constraint* at the end (when tables and functions exists). Because I have a function F `(Select COUNT (*) from table X)`, 
and I have a constraint on table Y with Check function

example:

```
Create function F
RETURNS int
QUERY....
RETURN SELECT COUNT (*) FROM TABLE X
END
GO

ALTER TABLE Y ADD Constraint ConstraintName dbo.Function F ()= 1
```

When I change order for procedures, the scripts fails for DROP FUNCTION (there is a reference in Y).

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `Traceability Link` of type `DBCreateAfter`, from table `Y` to function `F`, and from function `F` to table `X`.

This should fix the create, and the drop order.

Comment: Thank you for your advice - perhaps it would be route, but there are new feews problems.. 

In this table Y are many foreign keys :-) which also have some references to other tables....
Do I have to create Tracebilities to all (referenced) tables? 

There are in the script is DROP TABLE Y on the first place... 
but because of references to another tables the scripty does not work :-)

On the second place in the script is Drop Function (after drop TABLE Y - that is correct).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I've just tried to create an Oracle model. By default, the Foreign Key was generated as `outside` (as `alter table add constraint foreign key...` rather than `create table (... foreign key...`). This allows for circular dependency. This `outside`option is under `Database > Generate Database > Options > Foreign key`, once you have references in your model.